# Storing the text from objects in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to find out a way to store the text from HTML DOM objects in an JS array.

The following code returns text from  different 8 objects

```
   $('.invoice-number').text();
```

I would like to organize the text from each particular object in an array.

Something like (pseudo code):

```
foreach($('invoice-number').text() as x){
    var ary = Array();
    push(x,ary);
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each and push should do the trick

```
var ary =[];

$('.invoice-number').each(function() {
   ary.push($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` method:

```
var arr = $('.invoice-number').map(function(){
     return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Comment: What is the advantage to this seemingly complicated code compared to each and push?

Comment: @mplungjan I prefer to use `map` method, there is no significant difference, this is what jQuery offers. `map` uses `each` method internally.

Comment: Map method looks much cleaner then old school combination of `each` and `push`.

Comment: @dfsq There is nothing memorable to me about map(function() { return ...}).get(); I would need to look that up a few times to remember it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.each()`api to get every text of .invoice-number and put it to array.

jquery `.each` : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
var invoiceNumbers = [];

$('.invoice-number').each(function()
{
     invoiceNumbers.push($(this).text());
});
```